# Add parent tag with PHP HTML purifier

Tags: php, html, laravel, htmlpurifier

#### Problem

I have `.html` file without `<ul>`:

```
<div>
<li> <a href="#">1</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">2</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">3</a> </li>
</div>
```

After purifying it looks like this:

```
<div>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

#### Question

Is it possible to add parent `<ul>` tag around `<li>` with HTML purifier?

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#">1</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">2</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">2</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Or is it possible to keep it like it is without `<ul>`?

##### Side note

I'm using [mewebstudio/Purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier) package on the Laravel 8 project.

The package is based on [htmlpurifier.org](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

I didn't find anything useful in the [docs](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html) for my problem.

Comment: No good way to add a `<ul>` around the orphaned `<li>`s, I believe, but you can probably use [the Customize!](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) documentation to allow `li` tags as children of `div` tags. Sorry, this isn't quite an answer (hence a comment), but maybe it's enough of a direction for you to work with! :)